# Elixir Supervisor stops with :bad_return error

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor

Since 2 weeks, I tried to do a complete refactoring of our company Elixir app, because we had too many processes issue.

So I started from scratch, doing work step by step. And now, since almost 3 days I'm facing the same error, `:bad_return`, when I'm starting a worker in a supervisor. My process tree is this :

`Application
|- MainSupervisor
   |- Some workers (Extreme for EventStore, Repo for PostgreSQL, and a stream subscriber for eventstore)
   |- AccountStreamSupervisor
      |- AccountStreamDispatcher (Supervisor)
         |- StreamSubscriber (Worker)`

The dispatcher and subscriber have `start_child` function (so they will be used in runtime later)

I initialize my tree with `Supervisor.start_link/2` for each Supervisor. Application, MainSupervisor, AccountStreamSupervisor are starting without problem, but when it comes to AccountStreamDispatcher to be initialized, I have this `:bad_return` error.

The trace says that `init/1` of AccountStreamDispatcher is the problem, because it return `{:ok, #PID<0.392.0>` (which is, according to the doc, a good response).

I've tried so many things, like change `start_link` and `init` method signatures, change children declarations, always the same. I know that without my dispatcher, everything was launching correctly...

Here is some code :

```
defmodule MainSupervisor do
  use Supervisor
  require Logger

  def start_link(_args) do
    Logger.info("MainSupervisor => Starting...")

    result = Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, name: :main_supervisor)

    case result do
      {:ok, _} ->
        nil

      :ignore ->
        Logger.error("Unable start main supervisor because is ignored")

      {:error, {:already_started, _}} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start main supervisor because is already started")

      {:error, {:shutdown, reason}} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start main supervisor because #{IO.inspect(reason)}")

      {:error, reason} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start main supervisor because #{IO.inspect(reason)}")
    end

    result
    end

    def init(_) do
    Logger.info("MainSupervisor => Initializing...")

    event_store_settings = Application.get_env(:extreme, :event_store)

    children = [
      [...]
      %{
        id: ViewBuilder.V2.AccountStreamSupervisor,
        start: {ViewBuilder.V2.AccountStreamSupervisor, :start_link, []},
        type: :supervisor
      }
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

---

```
defmodule AccountStreamSupervisor do
  use Supervisor
  require Logger

  def start_link do
    Logger.info("AccountStreamSupervisor => Starting...")

    result = Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, name: :account_supervisor)

    case result do
      {:ok, _} ->
        nil

      :ignore ->
        Logger.error("Unable start account stream supervisor because is ignored")

      {:error, {:already_started, _}} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start account stream supervisor because is already started")

      {:error, {:shutdown, reason}} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start account stream supervisor because #{IO.inspect(reason)}")

      {:error, reason} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start account stream supervisor because #{IO.inspect(reason)}")
    end

    result
  end

  def init(_) do
    Logger.info("AccountStreamSupervisor => Initializing...")

    children = [
  %{
    id: AccountStreamDispatcher,
    start: {AccountStreamDispatcher, :start_link, []},
    type: :supervisor
  }
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

  def start_child(account_stream_name) do
    Logger.debug(
      "AccountStreamSupervisor => Start a new child - AccountStreamDispatcher with the name: #{
        account_stream_name
      }"
    )

    Supervisor.start_child(:account_supervisor, [])
  end
end
```

---

```
defmodule AccountStreamDispatcher do
  use Supervisor
  require Logger

  def start_link do
    Logger.debug("AccountStreamDispatcher => Starting...")

    result = Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, name: :account_dispatcher)
    IO.inspect(result)
    case result do
      {:ok, _} ->
        nil

      :ignore ->
        Logger.error("Unable start dispatcher because is ignored")

      {:error, {:already_started, pid}} ->
        Logger.debug("Dispatcher is already started with pid #{pid}")

      {:error, reason} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start dispatcher because #{IO.inspect(reason)}")
    end

    result
  end

  def init(_) do
    Logger.info("AccountStreamDispatcher => Initializing...")

    children = [
      %{
        id: StreamSubscriber,
        start: {StreamSubscriber, :start_link, []},
        type: :supervisor
      }
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, [strategy: :one_for_one])
  end

  def start_child(account_stream_name, type, account_id, sub_keys) do
    Logger.debug(
      "AccountStreamDispatcher => Start a new child - StreamSubscriber with the name: #{
        account_stream_name
      }"
    )

    Supervisor.start_child(
      :account_dispatcher,
      [
        %{
          stream_name: account_stream_name,
          stream_type: type,
          account_id: account_id,
          sub_keys: sub_keys
        }
      ]
    )
  end
end
```

---

```
defmodule StreamSubscriber do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  alias EventHandler.EventHandlerProvider, as: EventHandlerProvider

   def start_link(
          args = %{
            stream_name: name,
            stream_type: _type,
            account_id: _account_id,
            sub_keys: _sub_keys
          }
      ) do
    Logger.debug("StreamSubscriber => Starting... (#{name})")

    result = GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args, name: name)

    case result do
      {:ok, _} ->
        nil

      :ignore ->
        Logger.error("Unable start process #{name} because is ignored")

      {:error, {:already_started, _}} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start process #{name} because is already started")

      {:error, reason} ->
        Logger.error("Unable start process #{name} because #{IO.inspect(reason)}")
    end

    result
  end

  def init(%{stream_name: name, stream_type: type, account_id: account_id, sub_keys: sub_keys}) do
    Logger.debug("StreamSubscriber => Initializing... (#{name})")

    state = %{stream_name: name, stream_type: type, account_id: account_id, sub_keys: sub_keys}

    {:ok, _} = EventHandlerProvider.create_handler(type, name, account_id, sub_keys)

    {:ok, state}
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is correct:

```
   children = [
      %{
        id: StreamSubscriber,
        start: {StreamSubscriber, :start_link, []},
        type: :supervisor
      }
    ]
```

The value of the `start:` key tells the Supervisor how to start the child `StreamSubscriber`, and you are telling the Supervisor to call `StreamSubscriber`'s `start_link()` function with the argument `[]`, yet you defined `start_link()` in `StreamSubscriber` like this:

```
  def start_link(
          args = %{
            stream_name: name,
            stream_type: _type,
            account_id: _account_id,
            sub_keys: _sub_keys
          }
      ) do ...
```

But `[]` cannot pattern match a Map.

> I've tried so many things, like change start_link and init method signatures,

Maybe you posted some faulty code after trying to troubleshoot the problem?

Once you get the function calls to match the function defs, you can cure the `bad_return` problem by doing this:

> **[Module-based supervisors](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-module-based-supervisors)**
>   In the example above, a supervisor was started by passing the supervision structure to start_link/2. However,
>   supervisors can also be created by explicitly defining a supervision
>   module:
>
> ```
> defmodule MySupervisor do
>
>   use Supervisor
>
>   def start_link(init_arg) do
>     Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, init_arg, name: __MODULE__)
>   end
>
>   @impl true
>   def init(_init_arg) do
>     children = [
>       {Stack, [:hello]}
>     ]
>
>     Supervisor.init(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> The difference between the two approaches is that a module-based
>   supervisor gives you more direct control over how the supervisor is
>   initialized. Instead of calling `Supervisor.start_link/2` with a list
>   of children that are automatically initialized, we manually
>   initialized the children by calling `Supervisor.init/2` inside its
>   init/1 callback.

Inside all your supervisor's `init()` methods, you need to call `Supervisor.init()` instead of `Supervisor.start_link()`.  Here's the output I got when implementing those changes:

```
~/elixir_programs/app1$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> MainSupervisor.start_link(1)

20:42:11.324 [info]  MainSupervisor => Starting...

20:42:11.324 [info]  MainSupervisor => Initializing...

20:42:11.327 [info]  AccountStreamSupervisor => Starting...

20:42:11.328 [info]  AccountStreamSupervisor => Initializing...

20:42:11.328 [debug] AccountStreamDispatcher => Starting...

20:42:11.328 [info]  AccountStreamDispatcher => Initializing...

20:42:11.328 [debug] StreamSubscriber => Starting... #(Elixir.StreamSubscriber)

20:42:11.329 [debug] StreamSubscriber => Initializing... (Elixir.StreamSubscriber)
{:ok, #PID<0.214.0>}

iex(2)>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response ! For the parameter part, with the map, I know this is incorrect (I've tried without my pattern match (empty list) and it didn't worked too). For your module based explanation, I will try this now and go back to you once I've got results.

Comment: I finally make it work, my issue was `start_link`definition with multiple parameters. You must work with an array first.

Comment: I also used `DynamicSupervisor` type instead of `Supervisor` to initialize my child supervisors.